# How does, for example, pastie.org work? Where code comes in and posted elswhere in the right format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Im working on asp.net mvc4 and im a n00bie.. I have done all the groudwork of the website. With SQL server and LinQToSql framework.

I want to be able to get code and post it somewhere else where people get the change to share it with friends and stuff.

What i find as a problem is to put it in a right format, as in html.. how can set it in a html format.
Hope i am making my self clear..

And thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right side above the input field you will see a dropdown menu. Select HTML / XML.